# JPA manytoone relation delete operation

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

I want to delete  ExternalProcessed files  has same ExternalProcessedFileInfo  But this query fails.It is easy when  Relation reverted  to @onetomany  and cascade on delete but i didn't find any useful example for ManytoOne relations.

This is the code i want to run and it will run for select query .

```
javax.persistence.Query query =this. manager.createQuery("Delete  from  ExternalProcessedFile "
                + " f WHERE f.processInfo.source.name= :source ");
          query.setParameter("source",source.getName()) ;
          EntityTransaction tran=  manager.getTransaction();
          try{
           tran.begin();
          query.executeUpdate();
          tran.commit();
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProcessedFile")

public class ExternalProcessedFile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EID")
    private Long id;


     @NotNull
     @ManyToOne
     private  ExternalProcessedFileInfo processInfo;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProcessedFileInfo")
public class ExternalProcessedFileInfo implements Serializable {

    public ExternalProcessedFileInfo(){

    }
     public ExternalProcessedFileInfo(String processtime,ExternalDataStorage source){
        this.processTime=processtime;
        this.source=source;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EID")
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ExternalDataStorage  source;


    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "processtime")
    private String processTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

DELETE queries do not take cascades into account. You will have to fetch each entity and `entityManager.remove(..)` it.

Comment: what does it mean do not take cascade into account .I am not expecting  removing ExternalProcessedFile also  remove ExternalProcessedFileInfo .I am only want delete a group of externalprocessedfile based on their ExternalProcessedFileInfo propertie

Comment: perhaps the query fails because of constraint violations. You should deleted the child entities.

Comment: I want to delete records from externalprocessedfile which is owner side of relation and i think it is chield.And exception say Sql grammer exception.

Comment: I cange relation and owner side to  onemany  and solve problem but i think  jpa must support this query if i change delete to select query working.